# How did the Kurgan get his sword?

Tags: highlander-franchise, highlander

The Kurgan has an unusual segmented sword with spikes sticking out from the quillons.

How did he get his sword? It was made before 1541, which is when the Kurgan killed Ramirez.

Was it made by him? Stolen by him from one of his uncounted victims over the centuries? Was it made especially for him?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was made specially for him by a (British) master swordsmith, as revealed in [*Highlander Origins: Kurgan #2*](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/Highlander_Origins:_Kurgan#2). To thank him, the Kurgan gave him a bag of gold, then proceeded to rape his wife, kill him and then rape his daughter. And then he stole the gold back and took the sword.

[image]